# Как перевести str в bytes и расшифровать?

Tags: python-3.x, байты

```
"b'\xd0\x97\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd1\x83\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\x2c\x20\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd1\x83\xd1\x8e\x20\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\x21'"`введите сюда код`
```

как перевести в тип bytes? Методом decode не получается т.к. это тип str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "b'\xd0\x97\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd1\x83\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\x2c\x20\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd1\x83\xd1\x8e\x20\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\x21'"

result = s[2:-1].encode('latin-1').decode()
print(result)
```

```
Здравствуйте, приветствую вас!
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)